# IdentityServer4 Redirect to login action with client information

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

Is there a way to manage the redirect to the login page keeping the client parameters  in query string?

I created a forgot password page on Identity server and insert the redirect to login page

```
<a asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Account">Go Log in</a>
```

if i  try to go to this page and then go back to the login page by clicking on this  button. When I log in, the redirect url does not work and I remain on the identity server.

Comment: see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56250726/identity-server-registration-doesnt-redirect-back-to-react-app/56253566#56253566) and the reference inside my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to help you, but here is my answer.

I'm using implicit flow with client credentials, with the following settings on my client.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(option => {
                option.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                option.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";

            }).AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"];
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.FormPost;
            });
```

On the controller, you are trying to protect have an [Authorize] attribute.

in my client application, I have this.

```
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult performlogin()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }
```

That should redirect you to identity server to login.

My method signature to login on identity server is as follows.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl){
 // do login code and redirect
 // returnUrl should have the redirect path with query string.
}
```

And on successful login, redirect

I hope this helps